# Scraping data that only has <td> without specific class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I'm attempting to scrape data, but I am having trouble accessing individual elements. I want to extract the Title, Rank, Year, and Genre from each album but I can only access the entire row of data and not the INDIVIDUAL columns. Where the data is stored, every class says  but there is no class to specifically access each column of data.

I attempted to access them by taking each index of the array returned by the `find_all()` method, but I can only retrieve this data for the first album. The link to the website is https://www.popvortex.com/music/100-greatest-albums/. This occurs when I access the td tags of the table using `find_all()` and printing the list:

[image]

This is my attempt to print and store the column data individually.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.popvortex.com/music/100-greatest-albums/') 
    source.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml') 

    albums = soup.find(id='great-albums-table').find_all('td')
    for album in albums:
        rank = albums[0]
        artist = albums[1]
        title = albums[2]
        year = albums[3]
        genre = albums[4]
        print(title.text)
        print(artist.text)
        print(rank.text)
        print(year.text)
        print(genre.text)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This was the result of that attempt

```
Jimi Hendrix Experience
Axis: Bold as Love
100.
1968
Rock (only returns this and not the other albums)
```

This is the link for the website: https://www.popvortex.com/music/100-greatest-albums/

Comment: Please add your code as text and a [mcve] with an [edit]

Comment: Also remember to, [as per the rules](/help/how-to-ask), _not post pictures of text_. Just copy the text over (or copy-paste it). Unlike posting images, which you can't do with 1 rep yet, you can _always_ post text, and put it in code fences (with the correct syntax highlighting hint to make it easier to read for the people you're asking for help).

Comment: Also, your td's don't need classes... Your table has an ID. You can get an array **of rows**. (find `tr`, not `td`) Those rows are lists, all with the same number of columns. Use `row[2]`  to get the name

Comment: Is row a keyword? And when i put tr it says "ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" and when using find I only receive the first row which is the header

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data by first finding the tag `table`, then finding all table rows `tr` and then all `td`s.

The last column `Buy` in each row is a link and can be empty. Therefore it has to be treated differently.

Try this:

```
results = []
table = soup.find("table", id='great-albums-table')
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    tmp = []
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    for idx, elem in enumerate(cols):
        if idx != 6:
            tmp.append(elem.text.strip())
        else:
            if elem.find('a'):
                tmp.append(elem.find('a').get('href'))
            else:
                tmp.append(None)
    results.append(tmp)

# The top row of the retrieved table is empty 
# therefore we use results[1:] for the dataframe.
pd.DataFrame(results[1:], 
             columns=["Rank", "Album", "Artist", "Year", "Genre", "Points", "Buy"])
```

Print out:

```
    Rank    Album   Artist  Year    Genre   Points  Buy
0   100.    Axis: Bold as Love  Jimi Hendrix Experience 1968    Rock    484 https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/axis-bol...
1   99. Born in the U.S.A.  Bruce Springsteen   1984    Rock    487 https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/born-in-...
2   98. Kid A   Radiohead   2000    Alternative 488 https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/kid-a/id...
3   97. Goodbye Yellow Brick Road   Elton John  1973    Rock    493 https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/goodbye-.
```

Comment: @bananaboydan You're welcome! Glad that this helped. If this solves your question please accept this as the answer. Good luck with your project!